# Python timestamp for pcap files

Tags: python, parsing, timestamp, pcap

I am fairly new to Python, and i came across some code that parsed through a pcap file. The only problem is that this code contained the line datetime.datetime.now() which it would use to print out the time stamp for the connections in the file, however it prints out the times stamp of when it was just accessed. What i want to do however is to print out the original time stamps for the connections in the file.

For example, if i used the code to parse through the pcap file now, the first connection would have a time stamp of August 23, 2013 9:04 (or however specific it gets). Where as the file has the original time stamp of July 3, 2008 3:05 (which is what i want to actually print out).

I was wondering if anyone knew a simple python solution or any other help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

I am looking to get the time stamp for the packets in the file not the time stamp for the file itself.

Comment: Do you want the file system time stamp of the pcap file itself, or the time stamps of packets *within* the pcap file?

Comment: The packets within the pcap file were the ones i wanted the time stamps for

Comment: What code did you find to parse the pcap file?